# How to show a subtitle for each <li> in magento menu

Tags: magento

Hi I'm trying to put a subtitle or a second line in the magento menu. I find some code but not works editing the navigation.php of the default theme. Is possible using an attribute different for each category or adding an extra field in the general information tab in category administration?

Anybody has tried it?

Thanks!
Marc.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to create a local codepool extension and add an additional eav attribute called "subtitle" or whatever you want to category objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a method of creating an attribute for categories. Magento does not allow you to do this in a UI, currently.

If you want a pre-made extension, [DeltaCats](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/deltacats-6930.html) is the only extension I'm aware of in Magento Connect that allows you to do this with a full UI.

If you want to save money and do it yourself, [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/) has a tutorial that I have used myself, and can verify it works on Magento 1.6.